# Binding from XAML doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

When I create binding in code like in the following example, everything works fine:

```
 public partial class BindingToCustomType : Window {
    public Craftsman Craftsman { get; set; }
    public BindingToCustomType() {
        InitializeComponent();

        Craftsman = new Craftsman() {Age = 45, LastName = "Joe", Name = "Grok"};

        Binding binding = new Binding();  
        binding.Source = Craftsman;    
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Name");   
        NameBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataBinding.BindingToCustomType"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="BindingToCustomType">

    <TextBlock x:Name="NameBlock" Width="120" FontSize="16" Foreground="Red" />
</Window>
```

When I try to set that binding purely in XAML, it doesn't work:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="NameBlock" Width="120" FontSize="16" Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Source=Craftsman, Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Even if I set data context on the Window element, it doesn't work:

```
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

I don't want the solution to this problem.
I want to understand **WHY** this doesn't work in XAML either with DataContext, or without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would take a look at your Output in visual studio you would find the following line in your xaml binding.

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Name' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=538009415)'.
BindingExpression:Path=Name; DataItem='String' (HashCode=538009415); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name='NameBlock'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

This means that the

```
Text="{Binding Source=Craftsman, Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Is actually binding to a string literal 'Craftsman' and not the property of your window.

To get your bindings work you would need to set the datacontext for the window

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

And your binding could be either (this is stupid)

```
Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Craftsman.Name, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

Or very simply

```
Text="{Binding Craftsman.Name, Mode=OneWay}"
```

You could set a resource for the window

```
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApplication2:Craftsman x:Key="CraftsmanResource" Age="45" LastName="Joe" Name="Grok"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then use the binding

```
Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource CraftsmanResource}}"
```

Comment: But why this is working this way? I mean, I created the same binding in XAML the same way as I did it in code. Why in code works, in XAML doesn't? And what's the meaning of the Source property setting in XAML then?

Comment: In code you set the source to object of type Cratfsman, in xaml you are setting the source a *string literal* "Craftsman". Added example how you could use the Source in xaml.

Comment: Path is also initialized by a string, but it works. The Source property seems to me very tricky. It may sounds funny, but I've been working with WPF for 5 years and I've been using bindings all the time successfully, but I still find them very hard to understand, to understand how they really work under the hood.

Comment: There is a bunch of reflection going on with the xaml, basically setting Path=Name means "bind to a property named 'Path' in the DataContext". Setting Path=Craftsman.Name means that it would first search for Craftsman property in the DataContext and then get 'Name' from that. In code you set new PropertyPath("Name") and not "Name".

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to set the `Window` `DataContext` as you have but your Binding on the `TextBlock` is wrong.

Your XAML should be:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="NameBlock" Width="120" FontSize="16" Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Path=Craftsman.Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean that when we set a DataContext, the Source property becomes irrelevant?

Comment: And the other question is why can't we use Source without setting the DataContext?

Comment: In a way. `Source` is normally used for referencing something that's not a member of the `DataContext` object. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.data.binding.source(v=vs.110).aspx for an example. The `DataContext` is the direct association of a data source (whether that is the `Window` object it self or a `ViewModel` class) to the `FrameworkElement` binding scope. Without setting the `DataContext`, there is no data scope to bind to - `DataContext` is null by default.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of things to take note of.

1. You are creating the craftsman object after `InitializeComponent()`, so your Window doesnt know if it has changed. Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your window class for notification of `craftsman`. Or, create your object before `InitializeComponent()`. So, everything would be available right before Window is created, so first time binding will work.
2. In your first case, do this

   ```
           Craftsman = new Craftsman() { Age = 45, LastName = "Joe", Name = "Grok" };

           Binding binding = new Binding();
           binding.Source = TheCraftsman;
           binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Name");
           NameBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);

           Craftsman = new Craftsman() { Age = 45, LastName = "Joe", Name = "NewGrok" };
   ```

   TextBlock will keep showing Grok as value.
3. Your path is wrong, it should be `Text="{Binding Path=TheCraftsman.Name, Mode=OneWay}"`, Source is for values coming from resources/property-coming-from-element etc.

Conclusion : It's related to InitilizeComponent(), change notification, and your path.